# Unexpected end of file while looking for precompiler header file, when instrument my code through squish coco

Tags: visual-c++, squish, precompiler

> error C1010: unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled
>   header. Did you forgot to add #include "stdafx.h" to your source file?

I have already added #include "stdafx.h" file in my .cpp file

```
#include "stdafx.h"

msmq()
{

   int a;

    enter code here

}
```

But when I used [Squish coco](https://www.froglogic.com/coco/) for code instrumentation at that time they ignore this precompiler file and give me error.

I expect it to instrument my code successfully without giving C1010 error.

I already tried Precompiler Disable option, but it didn't work successfully

Comment: Coco usage is documented [here](https://doc.froglogic.com/squish-coco/latest/coveragescanner.html#cha%3Acommand-line-ref).  Since it seems to invoke the C++ compiler, you'll have to reproduce the same compile options.  Use Project > Properties > C/C++ > Command line to see them.  Tells you to use /Yu"stdafx.h"

Comment: @Hans Passant, already added in Command line. but it's not work

Comment: I recommend contacting the vendor of Squish Coco for support.

Comment: Okay,, i will try

Comment: Did you resolve this? I'm facing the same error and, actually, I'm hating squishcoco.

Comment: yes, because of some space error in header file.
ensure that between (#include) and ("Header file name") must have only one space.
#include  "stdAfx.h" ( 2 space beween #include and Header file name)
if you give only one space instead of more then one then simply solve it.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, because of some space error in the header file.

Ensure that between `#include` and `"Header file name"` there is only one space.

`#include  "stdAfx.h"` (2 spaces between #include and header file name)

If you give only one space instead of more then one then simply solve it:

`#include "stdAfx.h"` (only one space) it's work correctly..